# How to disable stylesheets in MS Edge without plugins

Tags: css, stylesheet, microsoft-edge

I tested a site for accessibility and I now have a QA validating that all of the changes were made. The QA needs to validate that the site is still readable with the stylesheets turned off. The QA can only use MS Edge and cannot install any plugins or browser extensions. Has anyone figured out how to turn off stylesheets? Googling this got me nowhere. When I evaluate the site, I use an extension in Chrome so I have never had this issue before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press F12 and copy this to console, hit enter

```
$('style,link[rel="stylesheet"]').remove()
```

Comment: Does not work.  `$('style,link[rel="stylesheet"]').remove()`
gives `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

(Looks like JQuery hasn't archived World Domination yet.)

Answer (score 3):

Vanilla JS approach.

```js
( [].slice.call( document.styleSheets ) ).map( function ( style ) {
  var node = style.ownerNode;
  node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
} );
```

ES6 Vanilla JS Version

```js
[ ...document.styleSheets ].map( ( style ) => {
  const node = style.ownerNode;
  node.parentNode.removeChild( node );
} );
```

Comment: ES6+ version:

```Array.from(document.styleSheets).map((style) => {
  const node = style.ownerNode;
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
});```